# Rough engine sound at 30-60 mph on a 2012 Toyota Camry

Tags: engine, noise, camry

I have a 2012 Camry, 4 cyl, whose engine has a random rough sound on a light acceleration, between 30 and 60 mph. It's very brief, but seems to be getting worse and more frequent. It doesn't happen when using cruise control or at speeds above 60. It is an automatic with manual option. I use a high grade gasoline and change the oil on it on a regular basis. Any ideas as to what this could possibly be?? I realize it could be a broad range of issues, but trying the process of elimination. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you mean "misfire under light acceleration"?

Comment: If you are going to tackle this yourself, then start by collecting some obd2 live data.  Record when it runs well, and then compare it to when it doesn't while paying special attention to the fuel trims.  If you don't want to go this route, then I suggest bring it to a good shop since so many DIY no-code diagnostics, or "the parts cannon", often costs much more than a professional diagnostic.

Answer (score 0):

When you are accellerating, you are no longer idling. Can you describe more of what is happening when you are accellerating? Is the car shaking or does it feel like the car is loosing power.

If it's shaking, you have an axle problem. You may want to replace your EGR valve and/or clean your throttle body.  Need more detailed info on what is exactly going on.